# Getting a list with every listeners on Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, listener

I would like to get a list with every listeners registered on my applicacion as well as their priority. That list should contain my own listeners and the listeners that Symfony core or other enabled bundles have registered as well.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to write code to display it on your website you can just use CLI:

```
php app/console debug:event-dispatcher
```

Comment: In newer versions of Symfony the console will be in `bin/console`

Answer (score 7):

You can get [event dispatcher](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.html) from container and take a look at events with `getListeners` function. Example in controller

```
$evd = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
$listeners = $evd->getListeners();
```

Description

```
/**
 * Gets the listeners of a specific event or all listeners.
 *
 * @param string $eventName The name of the event
 *
 * @return array The event listeners for the specified event, or all event listeners by event name
 */
public function getListeners($eventName = null);
```

Be careful, doctrine has own event dispatcher.

```
/** @var $em EntityManager */
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$evd = $em->getEventManager();
$listeners = $evd->getListeners();
```

Comment: I found it quite hard to get the info I wanted from the array which `getListeners` returned (sf 2.3).

I ended up writing the following to parse it: ``$dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher'); foreach ($dispatcher->getListeners() as $listeners) { foreach ($listeners as $listener); { foreach (listener as $details) { if (gettype($details) == 'string') { echo " ($details)"; echo '<br>'; } else { echo get_class($details); } } } }``